# QnAmaker Knowledgebase Privacy and Security

Tags: security, azure-qna-maker, cloud-security

Is there a way to identify the knowledgebase that we have created is not vulnerable and open for security threat? Can someone else break into the existing Knowledgebase and access our inhouse documents? We are keen to know about this so that we need to decide on whether to go ahead with this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides several resources that you can reference regarding privacy and security. The first [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/cognitive-services-compliance-and-privacy/) gives a simple overview of MS compliance and privacy. This [link](http://file:///C:/Users/v-stkanb/Downloads/Microsoft%20Azure%20Compliance%20Offerings.pdf) is a detailed report on Microsoft Azure Compliance Offerings that should answer any question you have. This last [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/compliance/complianceofferings) is Microsoft's compliance website where you can explore offerings across different regions, industries, and products.

Hope of help!